# How can I do other oprations on CPU while kenrels in GPU are running?

Tags: opencl

The kernel needs a few minutes to finish.
I want to display a moving bar in the console while the kernel in GPU is processing.

Normally, this funciton `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` executes the kernels, and when they are finished, CPU continues to execute the following operations like `clWaitForEvents` and `clReleaseMemObject` etc.

However, I want the CPU to print a processing bar continuesly after `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` but before the kernels finish.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create one thread that handles the GPU queue and one thread that handles the console output.
You can share information between the two threads by allocating global variables.

```c
#include <iostream>;
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

volatile bool not_finished = true;
float progress = 0.0f;

void do_console_output() {
    while(not_finished) {
        // do console output ...
        cout << progress << endl;
    }
}
void do_opencl_stuff() {
    while(not_finished) {
        // do OpenCL stuff ...
        progress += 0.01f;
    }
}

int main() {
    thread console_thread(do_console_output); // launch a separate thread
    do_opencl_stuff(); // execute this in the main thread
    console_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want ！